# Fuzzy logic in Python

Tags: python, fuzzy-logic

I'm searching for a good fuzzy library in Python but the ones that I'm finding are not being maintained and doesn't seem to add everything I need to create a Fuzzy system.

These are the ones I found so far: PyFuzzy, Peach and Fuzzpy.

Do you know of any good library? If not, is there any library in C#, Java or C++?

Comment: Have a look at [fuzzywuzzy](http://seatgeek.com/blog/dev/fuzzywuzzy-fuzzy-string-matching-in-python).

Comment: @RanRag: fuzzywuzzy is a fuzzy string matching module, not a generic fuzzy module

Comment: I understand the rules requires closing the question, but unfortunately I have the same problem - I have to choose a fuzzy logic library for python (or write my own if neccessary) and I would REALLY appreciate if I could read opinions from people who have some experience with existing fuzzy logic libraries. I noticed this situation on stackoverflow many times before - I need some overview and/or comparison of existing libraries/technologies, I find relevant question, but it's closed as "not constructive". But it would have REALLY helped me! But no, bureaucracy wins :(

Comment: there is scikit-fuzzy : https://pythonhosted.org/scikit-fuzzy/